# Ajax success function doesn't work second time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have made a form submit with `AJAX`, the first time it submits, it has the success function, however the second time it prints the success data in `accept_friend.php` instead of the `#requests_container`, like a normal PHP form.

```
$('.accept_friend').submit(function(){
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "../accept_friend.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function( data )
        {   
            $('#requests_container').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('ERROR');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

here is accept_friend.php

```
<?php

session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require "classes/class.requests.php";
require "classes/db_config.php";

$current_user = $_POST['current_user'];
$friend_id = $_POST['friends_id'];

$requests = new Requests($DB_con);
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
     $requests->accept($current_user, $friend_id);
}
?>
```

Comment: some html may help a suspicion of mine

Comment: @Jaromanda X what is the suspicion

Comment: that `.accept_friend` is part of the html that's being replaced - i.e. it's within `#requests_container`

Comment: @JaromandaX how can I fix that

Comment: if that's the case, there's already an answer that will fix it

Comment: @JaromandaX it does not seem to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103418/discussion-between-another-user-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: to be absolutely clear, are you saying that the HTML replaced definitely does include the `.accept_friend` button?

Comment: added an answer that is tested to work

Comment: @anotheruser, can you add your initial html as well as the html that is received in response to accept_friend.php?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are replacing the entire html in your `$('#requests_container')` and I am assuming that the `.accept_friend` button is also inside the same container.

If this is the case then try replacing your code with

```
$('#requests_container').on('submit', '.accept_friend', function(){
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "../accept_friend.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function( data )
        {   
            $('#requests_container').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('ERROR');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

This will keep your event alive even after the form button is removed and put back in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this and it does work for me (Firefox)

after you've clobbered your form, rebind the submit event to the submitter function

```
$('.accept_friend').submit(function submitter() {
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "../accept_friend.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {   
            $('#requests_container').html(data);
            setTimeout(function() { // may not be needed
                $('.accept_friend').submit(submitter); // rebind submit
            }, 0);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('ERROR');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```